# How to generate a new sequence of random numbers every day?

Tags: c#, random, random-seed

I'm making a daily challenge in a game. Every day should be a new challenge. My procedural generation uses a **random number generator**. Attempting the daily challenge twice (or two different users attempting it) should have the same results (the same sequence of random numbers).

I want:

- generate a sequence of random numbers.
- sequence must be the same every time I start generating in the same day
- get a different sequence of numbers each day

I think I should create a [`Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2) with a [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) as the seed, but I'm not sure how. `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` is a long and DateTime's seed is an `int`.

I do not want the `hours/minutes/seconds` to impact the randomness (aside from the boundary between yesterday and today). The answers I've found are all about passing the current time into `Random` (or how that's the default no-parameter ctor behaviour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// UTC ensures all users see the date flip occur at the same
// time. If you want the date flip to be local for the user's
// time zone, use DateTime.Today instead.
var date = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
// Generate a seed by combining the year and the day of the year.
// DayOfYear is always gregorian (ignores culture) and always in
// [1,366].
var seed = date.Year * 1000 + date.DayOfYear;
return new Random(seed);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to generate a sequence of random numbers once each day and store them, so that those numbers can be "replayed" to people who play the challenge during that day. This approach may be viable, for instance, if that challenge consists of a randomly generated puzzle game board. This approach also has the advantage that the application won't be tied to a particular RNG's implementation. See also my article on [seeded RNGs](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#When_to_Use_a_Seeded_PRNG).

Comment: "generate a sequence of random numbers once each day and store them, so that those numbers can be "replayed" to people who play the challenge during that day" -- I'm specifically trying to produce an RNG that can be re-init'd with the same seed and generate the same sequence of numbers all day long. So to replay the challenge, I'd re-init the RNG and get the same sequence of numbers and don't need to store them.

Comment: "application won't be tied to a particular RNG's implementation" Indeed, I want the same challenge for different platforms (PC/Mac/Linux/etc), but storing the number list would require a server to distribute the number lists to players. The [.NET documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2#Instantiate) "If the same seed is used for separate Random objects, they will generate the same series of random numbers." So it sounds like that the runtime will handle that for me.

Comment: For your purposes, then, it's "impractical to store or distribute the 'random' numbers or results (rather than the seed) for later use", so that my advice in this answer doesn't apply.